# Accessing the jQuery.sortable object from the jQuery.droppable object

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-droppable

I have 2 jQuery.sortable lists on the page, which are initialized like this:

```
var beingSortedSelector;

$(".list-1").sortable({
    connectWith: ".list-2",
    start: function (event, ui) {
        beingSortedSelector = ".list-1";
    }
}).disableSelection();


$(".list-2").sortable({
    connectWith: ".list-1",
    start: function (event, ui) {
        beingSortedSelector = ".list-2";
    }
}).disableSelection();
```

Within these lists might be a droppable item, whihc is initialized like this:

```
$(".list-item").droppable({
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
        if ( condition ) {
            $(beingSortedSelector).sortable("cancel");
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

If a 'condition' is met when the something is dropped onto a '.list-item' item, I want to cancel the sortable that the item came from. From the above code, I am attempting to do this using a global var to store the sortable. However, calling...

```
$(beingSortedSelector).sortable("cancel");
```

... does not seem to work - no errors in the browser console. Any ideas?

Comment: is code execution going inside `if` condition. Have you checked that by putting `alert` there?

Comment: Is the `condition` true?

Comment: The code executes to inside the if( condition ) {} block.